# XAML: How to trigger from a DataRow Style TO a DataGrid Cell Setter?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using a DataGrid in XAML.
I have a specific style defined for the mouseover on a row.
This is defined through the content of  `<DataGrid.RowStyle>` tag.

For a specific column (the last one), I want to insert an icon, which will be only visible on mouseover as well. To hide it on default state, I define a Foreground color to transparent, defined in `<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>` tag content.

Below the global XAML

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <!-- FIRST COLUMN DECLARATION -->
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Container}" Header="Container" Width="*">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>

            <!-- ICON COLUMN DECLARATION -->
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Icon}" Header="" Width="30" CanUserResize="False">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>

                <!-- DECLARE THE SPECIFIC TRANSPARENT COLOR -->
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" >
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <!-- MOUSEOVER ROW STYLE, which is not taken in account by second column -->
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF27222A"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF31A4CF" />            
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold" />
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

The problem is that a style defined in a cell overrides the style defined in a row. This is also the case on a mouseover situation, meaning that my trigger is not taken in account for that specific column (in other words, all the cells of the last column).

I tried to declare a Setter with TargetName as below, but did not succeed to make it work, mainly because I don't know where to set the x:Name without triggering error in the project.

```
 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF31A4CF" TargetName="IconCol" />
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Got it worked, but partially failed as I finally introduced C# code to handle the Cell styles.
I inserted some **EventSetter** for MouseEnter and MouseLeave in `<DataGrid.RowStyle>` tag

Below is the XAML updated part:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseDataGridRowStyle}">

                <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="Row_MouseEnter"/>
                <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="Row_MouseLeave"/>

                <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF27222A"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF31A4CF" /> 
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold" />
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF27222A" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF31A4CF" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold" />
                        </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Then, when events are dispatched to C# code, I directly access to the desired cell in order to apply the dedicated style during a MouseOver situation